# Найти экземпляр объекта/класса Javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket

Хочу написать "*патч*" для одной веб игры (На JS), весь код минифицирован, поэтому лезть в него не самая лучшая идея.

Игра создаёт WebSocket соединение, и мне надо будет отправлять некоторые данные через это соединение, возможно где-то в коде есть var sock = new Websocket(); и мне бы найти этот самый sock.

Comment: даже если вы его найдете, он скорее всего не доступен из-за замыкания

Comment: ну и "патч" звучит больше, как хак игры, что бы получить преимущество ;)

Comment: Обойдите все свойства объекта `window` и проверяйте, является ли свойство инстансом `Websocket`, например

Answer (score 1):

Переопределяй сам `WebSocket` или его метод до того, как кто либо им воспользуется.

Внутри своей реализации ты сможешь сделать необходимые проверки, отдать выполнение оригинальному методу и каки-то образом обработать возвращаемое значение.

Comment: Ну что-бы это сделать придётся всё таки лезть в код, и разбираться больше чем нужно в нём, а разбираться в минифицированном коде это удел психопатов которым уже не чего терять

Comment: @FunMelon зачем лезть в код? переопределите глобально класс и все, при создании получайте инстанс и делайте с ним что хотите

Comment: Я как-бы не прям гуру, не особо разбираюсь, не мог бы пожалуйста подробнее сказать как это сделать?

Comment: @FunMelon `window.WebSocket = YOUR_CLASS`